# Find function $F(s)$ such that $F(s+1) = F(s) - \frac{1}{(s-2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

I want to find a function $F(s)$ such that $F(s+1) = F(s) - \frac{1}{(s-2)^2}$. 
I first consider the function $\psi(s) = \frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)}$. Then I have $\psi(s+1) = \frac{\Gamma'(s+1)}{\Gamma(s+1)}$. Then I use the identity that $\Gamma(s+1) = s\Gamma(s)$, and the product rule of the derivative. I get $$\psi(s+1) = \frac{\Gamma(s) - s\Gamma'(s)}{s\Gamma(s)}$$ Then I have $$\psi(s+1) - \psi(s) = \frac{\Gamma(s) + s\Gamma'(s) - s\Gamma'(s)}{s\Gamma(s)}$$ which is equal to $\frac{1}{s}$. But I'm confused about to get the desired function from here. Could anyone help me please? Thanks!

**UPDATE** I take the derivative on the both sides of the equation and I get $$\psi'(s+1) - \psi'(s) = -\frac{1}{s^2}$$ Then I think that my next step would be shifting $s$ to the right by 2
**CONCLUSION** I choose my $F(s)$ to be $\psi'(s-2)$. Then I have $$F(s+1) - F(s) = -\frac{1}{(s-2)^2}$$ which is desired

Comment: Did you try to take a derivative of the last equation and shifting $s$...?

Comment: @Pedro I didn't. But I'll try it right now.

Comment: @Pedro I tried your hint and updated my post.

Comment: To find "a function" for this is easy.  To find a meromorphic function (as you did) is not easy.  But you did it!

Comment: Note that if $g(s)=\sum_{k \ge 0}\frac{1}{(s+k)^2}$ which clearly converges uniformly on compacts away from the non-positive integers, one has $g(s+1)-g(s)=-1/s^2$ so one can construct a $F$ as above which is represented in a series of simple fractions only; of course given the product representation of $\Gamma$, that is not surprising and the connection with $\psi'$ is clear, but the above representation is direct and doesn;t require any $\Gamma$ function theory

Comment: Let
$$F\left( s \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{f\left( x \right){{e}^{-sx}}dx}$$
Plug it into the difference equation then invert the transform; $f\left( x \right)=-\frac{x{{e}^{2x}}}{{{e}^{-x}}-1}$.  Then take the transform
$$F\left( s \right)=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }{\frac{x{{e}^{-\left( s-2 \right)x}}}{1-{{e}^{-x}}}dx}$$
This is the polygamma function.